# From univariate to joint convergence in distribution

Tags: distributions, convergence, asymptotics, bivariate

Let $X_n \rightarrow_d X$ and $Y_n \rightarrow_d Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are **i.i.d** standard exponential random variables. However, I do not have that for any $n$, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent.

Can I still have the result that for any continuous sets $A$ and $B$:

$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n \in A \cap Y_n \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)? $$

Which conditions on the dependence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ do I need to claim this?

Comment: What does "they become independent only when $n$ tends to infinity" mean?

Comment: Can you even say $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n \in A) = P(X \in A)$ here for all measurable $A$? That is not what I would call convergence in distribution, and I would expect $A$ need only be a continuity set  or something similar

Comment: You're right. $A$ is a continuous set. I updated the question.

Comment: (1) What's a "continuous set"??  (2) The question is strange, because it only assumes something about the *distributions* of the sequences of random variables.  That doesn't give you any information at all about independence.  Thus, your result has no basis.  As a simple counterexample, let $X_n=Y_n$ for all $n.$

Answer (score 2):

The comment of @whuber below the OP is crucial, and it brings into the surface a confusion that established notation can create to less experienced users like me.

When we write $X_n \to_d X$ we *only* mean $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ (these being distribution functions). Namely we only mean that the leading term of the sequence of $X_n$'s, viewed on their own, acquires at the limit a distribution that is the same as the marginal distribution of some $X$ random variable.
Same comments go for $Y_n$ and $Y$. But then, the information "$X$ and $Y$ are independent" *does not play a role*. We only used the symbols $X$ and $Y$ to invoke their marginal distributions, and *not* their possible statistical association. The fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent has no bearing on what happens to the limits of $X_n$ and $Y_n$, *because the limiting rv's for $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not necessarily $X$ and $Y$*. They may be the random variables $X_n \to_p W_x$ and $Y_n \to_p Z_y$, which may have the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, but they are *not* $X$ or $Y$. They just have the same *marginal* distributions. But then, $X$ and $Y$ may be independent while $W_x$ and $Z_y$ are not.

Only if we can claim, making additional assumptions (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/379971/28746), that convergence in distribution does imply convergence in probability, then the statistical relation of $X$ and $Y$ becomes relevant.

**In such a more narrow case,** if we have that $X_n \to_p X$ and $Y_n \to_p Y$, we can say the following:

Assume that $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are comprised of continuous random variables.
Then their joint distribution function $H_n(x,y)$ has a unique Copula representation

$$H_n(x,y) = C_n\big[F_n(x), G_n(y)\big].$$

Evidently, the Copula is a proper distribution function itself w.r.t $F_n(x), G_n(y)$.

Moreover the limit $C$ of $C_n$ itself will depend on the assumed dependence relation between the limiting random variables. These are assumed independent, so it follows that $C_n$ converges to the Independence Copula $\Pi = F(x)G(y)$.
Now, the limiting distribution functions $F(x)$ and $G(y)$ are continuous, so the convergence to them of $F_n(x)$ and $G_n(x)$ is uniform, and distribution functions are bounded. Also the product $F(x)G(y)$ is continuous so the Copula converges uniformly. So we can look at $C_n\big[F_n(x), G_n(y)\big]$ and see a composition of functions that each converges uniformly to its respective limit. It follows that
$$\lim C_n\big[F_n(x), G_n(y)\big] = C\big[F(x), G(y)\big] = \Pi[F(x), G(y)] = F(x)G(y).$$

In other words, under convergence in probability, some "regularity/smooth behavior" assumptions are sufficient, together with limiting independence, to obtain

$$H_n(x,y) \to F(x)G(y).$$

Comment: Re "it follows that $C_n$ converges to the Independence Copula:" why?  As far as I can tell, because the assumptions about the $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are only about convergence in *distribution,* you shouldn't be able to deduce anything at all about the dependence structures of the joint variables $(X_n,Y_n).$ In fact, let $X_n=X=Y_n$ for all $n.$  Don't all the stated assumptions hold (trivially)?

Comment: @whuber The OP writes that the limits $X$ and $Y$ "are i.i.d. standard exponential". So it appears that it is part of the premises here, that the limits are independent rv's .

Comment: @whuber Probably I am missing something here. I understand the distinction that may arise since we do not assume convergence in probability, but I have trouble describing it. Still thinking about it.

Comment: @whuber ok, I think I got it. If convergence is only in distribution, then the information "$X$ nd $Y$ are independent" is irrelevant and misleading -because with convergence in distribution, we only mean the convergence of marginal distribution functions, not convergence to some specific random variables. The shorthand symbols $X_n \to_d X$ is what does the damage. I will change my post accordingly.

Comment: Okay, let's return to my initial query: I still do not fathom how you deduce that $C_n$ converges to anything at all.  Exactly what additional assumptions are you making that would imply that?

Comment: @whuber I change my post so that my initial treatment now applies only under convergence in probability, so we now have limiting random variables, and not only limiting distribution functions. In such a case, I believe that the sequence of Copulas converges to the Copula that describes the relation between the limiting random variables, which are assumed independent. Ain't it?

Comment: Thank you -- I didn't catch the switch in the types of convergence because I was focused on what the question actually asks.  But the way the question is formulated suggests such a more flexible interpretation might be helpful, +1.